# How do you design a registration form?

Tags: website-design, forms, accessibility, color

I am trying to learn about registration forms, what should I be careful about when designing one? Is there any "best practice" or do you know any great websites with great examples of registration forms?

(For example, I like the facebook.com registration form, the one when you sign up the first time)

Comment: Agreed, I don't have enough rep to migrate it, can someone do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say you should Consider these things whenever you design a form  :

1. Make Your Form Easy to understand
2. Choose Your Colors Wisely
3. Make it short and sweet (long pages/details irritates)
4. Design logically and easy to complete
5. A high contrast, easy to follow flow

---

Some articles and books on how to design beautiful forms :

- [A Beautiful form](http://www.noupe.com/php/beautiful-forms.html)
- [How to Create effective form](http://slodive.com/inspiration/showcase/how-to-create-effective-signup-registration-forms/)
- [Signup forms must die – here’s how we killed ours!](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2009/03/16/signup-forms-must-die-heres-how-we-killed-ours/)
- [Ten Tips For User Friendly Online Registration Forms](http://thephantomwriters.com/free_content/db/r/user-friendly-registration-forms.shtml)
- [The Science of Form Layout](http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/web_forms.html)
- [Web Form Design: FIlling in the Blanks](http://www.lukew.com/resources/web_form_design.asp) (The bible of web forms)

---

Examples of registration forms and Inspirations :

- [Registration Forms SHOWCASE](http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/registration_forms/)
- [Web Form Design Patterns: Sign-Up Forms](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/04/web-form-design-patterns-sign-up-forms/)
- [40 Eye-Catching Registration Pages](http://designreviver.com/articles/40-eye-catching-registration-pages/)
- [Registration Form Design Examples](http://www.uipattern.com/registration-form-design-examples/)
- [42 Famous Log in and Registration Forms](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/20/42-famous-login-and-registration-forms/)

All Forms need a solid/Soothing visual structure to attract not to distract.......

Hope these things will help you....

Comment: That's a great collection of resources in one place.

Comment: Any thoughts on multipage forms vs. single page forms?

Comment: My thought on multipage forms is: don't. ;) Granted, sometimes you need to...

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend reading Caroline Jarrett and Gerry Gaffney's excellent *[Web Forms That Work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558607102)*. Some key points for you, from the same book:

1. Take as little information as possible. Are you just verifying that a user is old enough to view your content? "Are you 18? (yes/no)" is sufficient.
2. Ask what you're using the information for. Why do you need this-or-that particular field? If the info is being used by some other department in your company, pay them a visit. Ask if it's really that important. Ask 'real' people if they *actually* use the data.
3. Assume your users don't read any ancillary or explanatory text on the form.
4. Show the user that you care about their effort. Strive to re-use any info the user has already given your organization (even if that means a database lookup). Preserve the contents of a rejected form (e.g. don't delete my carefully worded application statement just because I entered my DoB as DD-MM-YYYY rather than MM-DD-YYYY)
5. Avoid too many negatives in your labels / questions. Long chains of 'nots' are hard for readers to parse, especially in complex sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty is easy, usability needs some thought. Personally I find many user registration forms 'half baked' for the following reasons:

1. The cursor is not in the 'first name' box - user needs to put in an extra click.
2. The enter key is not usually captured - this should be set to work like the tab key on text fields but not text areas.
3. Some validation is needed so that people who type in 'john smith' get reply emails that have 'John Smith', i.e. the data is tidied up at source.
4. The background/foreground colour combination of the in focus element needs to be highlighted - easy to do, so often not bothered with.
5. On submit you get nothing but a 'your form has been submitted' response - if that. Why not show the content of the autorespond follow up email?

I also find it weird that most 'pretty form' tutorials miss out on these basics - seems nobody tests stuff on their elderly relatives these days.

Comment: Can you provide any examples of such "bad quality" registration forms ?

Comment: Open your eyes. First registration form I come across: https://sourceforge.net/user/registration does not put cursor focus in the first box and makes no attempt at Title Case for the titles. Most CMS and ecommerce toolkits pay minimal attention to the usability matters I mention, this is a pity as 'Contact Us' can often be the second most important page on a website.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen pretty bad forms myself, I am just curious what other people see as a "bad" reg. form

Comment: Not bad but PLEASE don't auto-focus on a field on page load. That's a usability and accessibility pain in the butt.

Comment: @DA01 Please qualify! The Google homepage has auto-focus on page load and most people do not have any problems with that. Sweeping statements have to be self evident.

Comment: I would hope it is self evident. Modifying the normal behavior of a web page/browser is typically seen as a universal usability no-no. It's also big accessibility problem. If I were to load your form, my screen reader would start reading "Form, First Name". A user may want to read the title of the page. Or intro paragraph first. If they want to jump to the form, they can. Google is always an exception. Typing 'google.com' is fairly self evident (I'm going to search) and that's pretty much the only thing one does on the google home page. (Still, I find it very annoying)

Comment: Good points, but for a registration form? You want them to have the whole page read out top to bottom or straight to the form? The internet is all about speed, doubly so if you have accessibility problems. "is typically seen as a universal usability no-no" - could you be any more vague? That is asserting a viewpoint from on high and not the reasoned discussion that SE is for.

Comment: @DA01 - Using your criteria, just as "typing google.com is fairly self-evident", clicking on a "Register" link is pretty much self-evident as well - you are asking to register for the system.

Comment: @Theodore, you want a user to know what the form is. If it's already intuited via the first field label, putting focus on it makes sense. If people would normally need to read the title/intro paragraph, putting focus there probably makes more sense. As Charles states, if it's a rather simple form with a specific task that a person purposefully got to from navigation, I agree...it's a lot less off an issue to apply auto focus. (though I don't necessarily believe auto-focusing saves people much time, but that's a different issue...)

Answer (score 1):

Luke Wroblewski is the godfather of web forms design. I'd recommend anything he's written:

http://www.lukew.com/

He has an excellent blog that's often full of quality statistics:

http://www.lukew.com/ff/

And his book ain't bad either:

http://www.lukew.com/resources/web_form_design.asp

I should also summarize Luke's philosophy on this (which he has plenty of great data to back it up with):

- avoid registration forms altogether. Ideally, you'd let a person use the site right away. SE is a model of that.
- If you must have a form, ask for the absolute bare minimum of information.
- Consider leveraging an existing login API as an option for the user (google, facebook, twitter, etc.)
- Decide if some of the information you are asking for in initial registration could be asked for later...ideally in context with a particular feature/task. (for example, maybe you don't NEED their country until they decide to use some sort of regional search...you can then ask for it then.)

Comment: I'd add that he's also a great speaker. Do catch him if you ever get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid optional fields.

Use relevant content groupings to organize forms.

Field width can provide valuable affordability.

[Best Practices for form design](http://www.slideshare.net/psykoreactor/best-practices-for-form-design)

Recent research show when form label is top align, Users capture label and text field with single eye movement  and the completion time is fastest.

[Input form label alignment top or left?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8480/input-form-label-alignment-top-or-left)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Ultimate Guide How to Optimize Registration Form for Higher Conversion](https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-optimize-registration-form-conversion-rate)

It covers:

1. Monitor your signup process
2. Fewer fields is more conversions
3. Provide social login button
4. If you need a lot of information - split it
5. Top-left aligned labels are best for readability & completion
6. Communicate expectations and errors clearly
7. Design better forms
8. Use a benefit-oriented headline and CTA
9. Make CTA button stand out