# Why might right aligned field labels be better?

Tags: forms, guidelines, gui-design, design-principles

For the longest time, I've used left-aligned labels in my forms, like this:

[image: Left Aligned Labels]

I did this because I thought having the labels left aligned made it easier for readers to scan the list of labels.

However, I found my axiom challenged recently while watching [the video of Billy Hollis' talk](http://ndc2011.macsimum.no/SAL3/Onsdag/1020-1120.wmv) from [NDC 2011](http://www.ndc2011.no/), in which Billy asserts that right-aligned labels are simply better, like this:

[image: Right Aligned Labels]

I've done a bunch of research and found a lot of discussion, including [this UX question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8480/input-form-label-alignment-top-or-left), which compares and contrasts the approaches, but nothing definitive.

In particular, I haven't been able to find anything to indicate why Billy Hollis changed his opinion from left- to right- alignment for labels (apparently he switched around 2007).

I figure Billy's too smart to have made the change without evidence - so I'm interested in seeing that evidence for myself.

Comment: The short answer is that people don't scan the list of labels, so any win from having them left-aligned is lost. People look at one label, then enter text, then look at the next label.

Comment: Also worth considering mobile when designing forms for the web http://www.uxbooth.com/blog/mobile-form-design-strategies/ Hope that helps :)

Comment: I remember a (German) conference poster where this question was studied empirically: Patrick Fischer, Theo Held, Martin Schrepp, Bettina Laugwitz: Wahrgenommene Ästhetik, Ordnung und Komplexität von Formularen. Mensch & Computer 2006: 441-443

Comment: @AlexFeinman that might be true for typical contact/order form but there are also admin areas where you typically read labels because you want to update only one exact field (like when you're on the phone with the customer and you need to quickly find & change something)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Luke Wroblewski wrote about this in [Top, Right or Left Aligned Form Labels](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?504) (April, 2007).

In it, he references eyetracking data from an article by Matteo Penzo called [Label Placement in Forms](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php) (July, 2006). Matteo drew several conclusions from this study, including that **right-aligned labels have a lighter cognitive workload** for users:

> **Alignment of labels**—In most cases, when placing labels to the left of input fields, using left-aligned labels imposes a heavy cognitive workload on users. Placing labels above input fields is preferable, but if you choose to place them to the left of input fields, at least make them right aligned.

It's possible Billy saw Luke's article and changed his stance based on it.

Comment: In Luke's latest book "Web Form Design" (chapter 4) he says top-aligned is the fastest, right-aligned is second fastest and a good choice if vertical space is an issue, and left-aligned is slowest but a good choice if you want people to read the labels carefully.

Comment: in the web it's generally horizontal space that is scarce rather than vertical since most people expect to be able to scroll vertically, rather than horizontally. In small mobile screen this become even more pronounced. I almost always top-align unless there is a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: If you're placing the labels on top of the text fields, consider adding substantial vertical space above the label, to group the label together with what it's labeling, and to avoid the confusion as to whether the label applies to the text field below or the one above. It almost always applies to the one below, but I believe it's a bad idea to make the user stop to think about that, even for a fraction of a second.

Comment: I'd love to hear how is this related to ERP & CRM systems where people are watching the same interface all over the day - my guess is that left-aligned labels will be better for "update one field in this big form" types of tasks

Comment: The study doesn't mention how many participants there are, was probably composes of a non-representative group of users, only tested a single form with just four fields, and most importantly: is only a single "ad-hoc" (their words) study. I would be *very* careful in drawing conclusions from this (in fact, the *only* serious conclusion one can draw from such a study is that more study is needed).

Answer (score 21):

Right-aligned, definitely.

You can see this as a function of the [Gestalt Grouping Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping): objects that are close together will be visually parsed together and interpreted as belonging together. Obviously, this is useful so people can read smoothly from label to text field. Therefore, by right-aligning the labels next to their corresponding text-fields, you are creating easier readability, because your visual system naturally pairs up the label with the field.

In the example you show, I would even move the labels slightly closer to the text-fields than they are already, since the fields themselves are closer to each other (again, implicit grouping) than the labels and fields are, and we know that proximity is generally the most important cue for grouping ([Quinlan & Wilton, 1998](http://www.perceptionweb.com/abstract.cgi?id=p270417)). It takes the brain longer to process text than it does to make decisions about where shapes are ("where?" usually gets answered before "what?"), so it's worth making that as easy as you can for the reader, IMO.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes I'll position my labels immediately above or sometimes immediately to the left of form elements.  It simply depends on space constraints of the page I'm working with.  But once I make my decision I'm consistent it with it.

There are a couple guidelines I follow for each case:

1. If you place the label above the textbox, make sure you provide *ample* spacing underneath the textbox.  You don't want the user to confuse labels because they're too tightly stacked.
2. If you place the label to the left of the form element, *always* right align the label.  It makes it much easier to connect the label to the textbox at a quick glance.  This is especially true when the labels vary greatly in length.

I believe that the most important thing here is not for the user to be able to scan the labels quickly as if they were a list, but rather, to associate the labels to their respective form elements as quickly and effortlessly as possible.

Comment: Right: the user isn’t scanning the labels trying to pick out a specific one; they’re looking at each field and trying to figure out what they have to do with it.

Answer (score 9):

I recently carried out an extensive usability study into the design of web forms and these were my key conclusions:

1. The best alignment is around a central axis (i.e. right-aligned labels and left-aligned fields).
2. A different alignment can work just as well *if* field highlighting is used (a coloured outline or highlight over the field currently being used).
3. User validation messages should be in-line and integrated with help tips and confirmation - i.e. as a user enters a field, something appears next to it explaining what to do, and as they leave it they either get "there's a problem" or "that's great" (usually in the form of symbols like ticks and crosses).
4. Continuation buttons should be on the bottom right (despite some theories put forward based on eye tracking!), should be in lower case / sentence case, and should show direction (e.g. an arrow pointing to the right).

Of course I learned much more but hopefully these key points above will help you! They're by no means ground-breaking, really just confirmation of what we thought we already knew.

Comment: Is this published anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

There's [a great discussion](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/01/label-alignment-in-long-forms-paper-prototyping-for-engineers.php#labelAlignment) of all sides of this argument at UX Matters.

The short version is that there are different situations where different methods work best. I'm currently building a very long form where the most important task is scanning the list of fields for the one you want to enter some data into. In this case, I've opted to go left-aligned. For shorter forms or forms where each all fields are going to filled out in sequence, right-aligned is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

Labels closer to fields have always been more usable due to the [principle of proximity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping). This is because "the brain groups together the elements instead of processing a large number of smaller stimuli, allowing us to understand and conceptualize information more quickly."

What's even more usable than right aligned labels are top aligned labels. It gives users closer proximity to fields, but it also helps mobile users see the label when they zooming into a field. And when labels get long from language translations, users will still be able to see the label since it's above the field, not to the side where it can get cut off. See the article below for visual examples.

> [Another Case for Top Aligned Form Labels](http://uxmovement.com/forms/another-case-for-using-top-aligned-form-labels/)

Answer (score 2):

One comment on left aligned labels that like better than right. Most comments have been referring to only the labels and associated fields, the one thing not being considered is white space and balance of the overall form. Using jagged left edges creates a strong sense of  imbalance when the user first looks at the form (while processing a user looks at one field at a time, that's true, but when the form first opens, the user scans the entire form and the resulting first impression has a significant impact on whether they "like" or "dislike" the program in general.

Comment: I don't buy the imbalance argument - there are plenty of succesful websites and other applications with asymetric layouts. Plus, if usability and style ever conflict, usability should win.

Comment: I agree with Karl; the visual asthetics are very important. (To me, right-aligned looks unprofessional, even though the cognitive workload may be smaller on small forms, but that's my personal opinion.) A good reference book that talks about alignment (and fonts and other visual UX issues) is "The Non-Designer's Design Book" by Robin Williams.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage to left-alignment I can think of is if most fields are irrelevant to each user. In this case, you need to left-align to help users pick out the fields they need (because they read web pages in F-shaped patterns, and find things best when they're 'docked' to the margin).

Then again, if most of your fields are irrelevant, there's probably something wrong with your form. You might split it into different variants for different types of respondent, or look at pruning extraneous fields.