# Anything I could do to improve my sign up form?

Tags: usability, forms, user-behavior, users, user-expectation

So I think that I'm finally at a point where I can say that my sign up form for desktop users is pretty much done.

I've tried to make it user friendly at first sight by keeping it as short as possible based on my requirements. And also by having a bit of text under each input that explains what it will be used for.

I would like to know if there is anything I've missed that I should have included that would enhance the UX?

**Form** (made it a little smaller so it'd fit on this page):

[image: Sign up form]

Comment: I love it. It's clear, simple, and not too many fields that I have to fill in. It looks nice too.

Comment: it's quite good! Only one thing looks sloppy for me - is an alignment of title (CREATE an Account) and Description text (Enter your info...). Move Description to the right a little bit (; But it's more visual design instead of UX (: Anyway - good work!

Comment: How are you going to handle error messages?

Comment: Any particular reason why you have confirm email but not password?

Comment: Because if the email is correct they can always request a new password that will be sent to their email, in case they forgot their password. Also the email will be used to send a verification link upon signing up.

Comment: One minor niggle, "We will reference to you by this name" is bad England.

Comment: I am aware of that, and has already been corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

[image]

1. Intro text adds nothing
2. Name is not essential to create account, or at least make it one field
3. Re-enter email is redundant
4. The way you aligned labels is not optimal
5. New password? I don't have any existing password at this point, am I?
6. Choose one colour for your links that is not red and not the same colour your headers have
7. Consider showing your tooltips only to the focused field

Comment: In what way are the labels not optimal aligned? I don't think there is something wrong with them.

Comment: Well, when you aligning labels you can do it three ways: on top of the field (best, consumes vertical space), to the left & left aligned (good enough), and to the left & right aligned (worst, use only with short labels).

Comment: I get that's your vision, but **why** is left & right aligned worst? I believe is even easier to associate the right label with the right input field then with left & left aligned labels.

Comment: Because we read left to right? So with right aligned labels each time I'm looking for a new line I need to focus. Each time I have to focus I'm spending my cognitive resources, which are very limited. I'd rather spend them to enter my password right. With left aligned  labels it's easier, but I still have to jump between a label and a corresponding field. With labels placed on top, everything goes naturally. You can say that's my vision.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/8874/46613

Answer (score 0):

Quoting a respected member of the User Experience community I can recommend some things to further enhance user experience.

Note: I think the form already is very clear and probably user friendly.

[image: People perceive name as a "single coherent entity"]
[resource article link](http://baymard.com/blog/mobile-form-usability-single-input-fields)

Not splitting first and last name is tricky on a back-end level. The application might want to address the user just by it's first or last name. Having those separated in the database makes this easy. But the name as a single entity, how do you know what the first name is and what the last? Different countries have different ways of displaying names. If you really need to separate the two entities you should do so with two input fields. Or perhaps you know your audience to be primarily US or UK based. Majority of your audience will have just a single first name and a single last name, making it easy to split the name into first name and last name.

[image: Forgetting to accept terms is a common form mistake users make]
Forgetting to accept the terms of service is a common mistake users make. Since accepting the terms is mandatory reducing it to a single button reduces the amount of clicks and the frustration of having forgotten to check the checkbox.

Comment: _"On desktop sites, there may be instances where dividing a single input entity across multiple fields may be acceptable if all the fields are either required or optional and there’s no misalignment between user perception and form design."_ I will have something different for mobile users.