# Ragged edges vs. alignment

Tags: layout

In an enterprise application I have a list of items and their statuses, and we can't agree on the layout.

Some people are bothered by the ragged edge that's created on the left in the first version. They insist on aligning the statuses to the right.

Others are bothered by the distance that's created between the items and their statuses in the second version, and they insist on the first version.

Other options like moving the status to the left of the names or creating a dedicated column a bit to the right of the names have been considered and dismissed.

Each line has a good visual frame of its own and they're pretty wide apart (vertically), so even if the statuses are moved to the right, it's very unlikely for users to misalign a status to the wrong name, so that's not a concern.

This takes up the entire width of the screen.

How can we settle this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVh44E.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: When you say "people" who are you referring to, users or developers?

Comment: Developers and PMs.

Comment: I would say that you could use the same guidelines as for form fields.  Eg: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8480/input-form-label-alignment-top-or-left/8482#8482.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit I'll explain why I don't think it's relevant. Noone would put field labels on the other side of the screen. Fields without labels are meaningless, but the names in my example are the primary pieces of information. Also, this is not a form that needs to be filled out - it's a grid. Stacking information within a grid row has its uses, but it's not the case here, so I can't put statuses above names, or the other way around. I'm not worried about path to completion or about conversion. In short, I think it's a very big stretch to use form guidelines for this.

Comment: I would say this kind of nitpicking is common in teams which are heavily biased towards the "analytical" end of the spectrum (i.e. all software development teams). How I like to handle this is to ask for suggestions individually, rather than let them go head to head in a meeting. Ask them questions, and they become less stuck on their viewpoint.

Comment: @Vitaly I would canvas users as they are the people who will be using the product.

Comment: Why has a dedicated columns for the statuses been dismissed?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Mostly because there is huge variance in the names of the items. "A reasonable location" got pushed further and further to the right, until it was the same as aligning them to the right :).

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: Then set a limit on the left column. If it's too long, cut it off and put an ellipsis, then use a mouseover to reveal the rest of the text.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When I do something like this, I make those two a table, bold / right-align the left column, and then it looks nice and even. The result ends up being something like this:

[image]

Comment: This format is common in Apple's mobile designs.

Comment: @Milo Cool, I never would have guessed. It's just something I picked up from a coworker once.

Comment: An example I can think of is in the App Store under the information for an app.

Answer (score 35):

"How can we settle this?"

You can get everyone in a room, give everyone boxing gloves and the last man standing wins!

Or...

Do two designs and split test them. Have the end user decide which is better. You can debate it all day long (as I'm sure you did today) but in the end, nobody will be right and nobody will be wrong. So, if you have to satisfy multiple people in your company, take the decision making process out of their hands and give it to the people that really matter...The customers.

p.s. if you want my opinion, start the statuses at the farthest most edge of the name column i.e.

```
name          [status]
long name     [status]
longest name  [status]
```

and then zebra stripe them

Comment: *Other options like ... creating a dedicated column a bit to the right of the names have been considered and dismissed* :).

Comment: Again, do multiple designs and let the end user choose. Design by committee always ends in disaster.

Comment: "Let the user choose"? Really? You're supposed to do usability tests and gather actual data. If you're just going to ask the user for an opinion then you might as well forego the tests.

Comment: @Aaronaught Yes, really. To test something like this, you'll need to define a goal. So, maybe we want the time on this page to decrease. Doing so indicates less confusion (This may or may not be the case, it's just an example). Put up two options. The one that decreases the time on the page wins. It's not a conscious decision from the end user. It's about getting them to achieve a goal.

Comment: Fine, but that's what I'm saying. You don't *ask* the user, you don't *let them decide*, you *test* the interaction using some objective metric like completion time.

Comment: @Aaronaught you're arguing semantics.

Comment: I'm arguing about 30 years of usability research and the difference between a usability test and a survey. You shouldn't advise people to "have the end user decide" - maybe *you* know what you really meant by that, but the reader may not. Besides, as a usability professional (I assume that's your profession) you should care about clear communication.

Comment: @Aaronaught - Understood. However, I donate my time here, I'm not getting paid. I do my best, but I'm busy. Read the answer "Do two designs and split test them". It's pretty clear what I'm advising.

Comment: No, it's not clear. It could just as easily be interpreted as "do two designs and ask users which one they like better" vs. "do two designs and measure which one leads to a faster completion time". Honestly, if this is about time, how much less time would it have taken to just edit two words in the post than it did to have this dialogue?

Comment: @Aaronaught It is perfectly clear to me, too. He refers to a "split test" which cannot reasonably be interpreted as a "survey." It is a type of A/B testing. Just because you misinterpreted doesn't mean what he wrote was ambiguous. It has been understood correctly by at least 30 people at the time of this comment. I think it is reasonable for him to conclude that your confusion is an isolated case and thus not worth editing the answer for. If you feel so strongly, why don't you edit it?

Answer (score 13):

Paul's solution is great: left aligning both the first and second column.

Alternatively, you could go for smaller labels, and divide the information into separate columns.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There are opinions on this topic, and there are a lot of guidance to it. From a readability perspective based on science (I was told in my bachelor education), you could also use the one line approach. This means that you center your name/value pair along a single line instead of two lines.

Reading this content downward the user only has to follow one line and don’t have to stretch nor guess which label belongs to which content. The blue line in the following mockup represent that (and shouldn’t be present in production).

A study of eye tracking data from an article by Matteo Penzo called [Label Placement in Forms](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php) (July, 2006). Matteo drew several conclusions from this study, including that **right-aligned labels have a lighter cognitive workload** for users:

> **Alignment of labels**—in most cases, when placing labels to the left of input fields, using left-aligned labels imposes a heavy cognitive workload on users. Placing labels above input fields is preferable, but if you choose to place them to the left of input fields, at least make them right aligned.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyVMNE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Now, you don't have input fields in your outline, but I'd say it's safe to say that a highlighted value to the right is as close as you get to a real input field.

Comment: Benny, you're talking about forms, please see my answer to Jørn.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky I know and I wrote it at the end of my answer. But because of the layout of the statuses I believe it is still valid för your design when it comes down to readability. Following one line instead of two puts less cognitive load on the user.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with @PaulDessert.  A/B test the two against a user sample and see which sticks.

Personally, I think neither are ideal. The ragged edge is hard to read, while the right-ranged visually associates statuses to secondary content (which I don't think you intend).

That said, my eye is drawn to #2 and, if you were to do that, I would either zebra stripe the rows or put in *subtle* range markers b/w text and label, eg
`Name........................... [Status] |-----------|
Longer Name............ [Another Status] | Secondary |
An even longer name........ [And Status] |-----------|`

Answer (score 2):

Your second option is perfect for eyes fitness, but could slow down information processing.

In typography they call this [**River effect**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_(typography)) and try to eliminate it:

> A carefully composed text page appears as an orderly series of strips
>   of black separated by horizontal channels of white space. Conversely,
>   in a slovenly setting the tendency is for the page to appear as a grey
>   and muddled pattern of isolated spats, this effect being caused by the
>   over-widely separated words. The normal, easy, left-to-right movement
>   of the eye is slowed down simply because of this separation; further,
>   the short letters and serifs are unable to discharge an important
>   function—that of keeping the eye on "the line". The eye also tends to
>   be confused by a feeling of vertical emphasis, that is, an up & down
>   movement, induced by the relative isolation of the words & consequent
>   insistence of the ascending and descending letters. This movement is
>   further emphasized by those "rivers" of white which are the
>   inseparable & ugly accompaniment of all carelessly set text matter.

[image]

As name−status pairs suggest sequential reading, I think it worth to consider Rivers effect. In your second UI rivers become ocean, so I'd prefer other layout.

Another disadvantage is caused by proximity from Gestalt principles. Currently names and labels look less related.

Paul's solution fixes these issues and has good aesthetics.

Comment: A river effect is when you have a vertical streak of white inside a block of text. Having some content on the left side of the screen and some more content on the right side does not mean that you have river effect there :)